# How to create table using angular from inside request callback function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a table using angular. The problem is that I need to create that table based on JSON response from my http request (at which point I call the responseHandler function below:

```
function call(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: "GET"
        , success: function (response, status, xhr) {

            responseHandler(response);
        }
        , error: function (xhr, status, error) {}
    });
}

 function responseHandler(response) {
    var data = angular.fromJson(response);
    var user = angular.fromJson(data['users']);
    userdata = user['data'];// this is correctly assigning the data I 
                                // need to the variable userdata
    var tApp = angular.module('tApp', []);
    tApp.controller('tCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.userdata = userdata;
        $("#usertable").css("visibility", "visible");
    }]);
 }
```

Here is my html:

```
<div ng-app="tApp" ng-controller="tCtrl" class="tab-content clearfix" id='tCtrl'>
<table id='usertable' border="1">
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in userdata">
                            <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.picture.data.url}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
</div>
```

I keep getting the angular.js:14516 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] error.
So it seems my controller is not being recognize by angular. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you call `responseHandler()` ? Please add this part.

Comment: try to put responseHandler inside your controller

Comment: @jitender this will not work ...

Comment: I call responseHandler from my ajax request via $.ajax

Comment: Please add this part. I think your main problem is: mixing AngularJS with jQuery.

Comment: This is a abuse of AngularJS ...  but I see no reason for your error. It should work.

Comment: Is there any other error in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your angular module and controller are declared **only** on success. But you are using `ng-controller` in your view. So if the request fails, you're in trouble :)

When `AngularJS` sees an `ng-controller` directive, but cannot find the matching controller, it throws that error. [Here is more info on the error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg)

But in general, there are issues with your code:

1. you should use `angular's` `$http` module to make http calls. You should not use `jquery` because it will not trigger a digest cycle once a response is received and `angular` will not know anything about the api call.
2. you should not create your angular module inside another function, just create it globally

Comment: This is simply wrong. You can declare your AngularJS app async on a loaded DOM. As you can see here https://plnkr.co/edit/Wny8GhN65S9vz4vuiJjy?p=preview 1) This is a refactoring hint. 2.) This wrong too. It's a good practise to wrap your AngularJS into a function in some cases e.g. testing.

Comment: if the request fails, will the app stil be declared?

Comment: Yea m8, I know it. But your answer is not solving the problem and including wrong recommendations on possible actions.

Comment: and (1.)This is a refactoring hint) ? have you heard about something called a digest cycle?

Comment: No, never heart about this. I started my developer career today =) well m8, nothin offense but you should understand my feedback. This is not ment to be a provocation. It's just the truth. As I explained, your answer doesnt solve the users question.

Comment: `AngularJS app -> no AngularJS error` is also not correct. As long as you have angularJS (the library) loaded, you will still get errors because of `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives in the view

Comment: Right, is the only point that is true but you said no word about this in your answer. But this also does not solve the users error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular, you should completely stop using JQuery, the asynchronous ajax call will mess up your application really hard because of angular's digest loop.

It's also a best practice to split the data-fetching into a different service, as it sometimes gets messy really fast and pollutes the controllers with a lot of code without application logic.

And because you don't use JQuery, you don't need to place ID in elements.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="tApp" ng-controller="tCtrl" class="tab-content clearfix">
  <table border="1" ng-show="userdata.length > 0">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in userdata">
      <td>{{x.name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.id}}</td>
      <td>{{x.picture.data.url}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var tApp = angular.module('tApp', []);

tApp.factory('dataFetchingService', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    getUserData: function() {
      $http.get('/someUrl/to/userData')
        .then(
          response => response.data,
          error => console.error(error)
        );
    }
  };
}]);

tApp.controller('tCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataFetchingService', function ($scope, dataFetchingService) {
    $scope.userdata = [];

    dataFetchingService.getUserData().then(userData => {
      $scope.userdata = userData;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: This is also not solving the users problem. There is no digest error as you can see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Wny8GhN65S9vz4vuiJjy?p=preview As I already said, while the users approach is a abuse to AngularJS it should work. He tried a stupid way, but it should work. I appricate your answer but it its a refactoring hint not a solution to his problem.

Comment: I didn't said there were, I just hinted to him that it's not the "angular way" to achieve what he wanted.
Ajax calls should be done after the application is bootstrapped.

Comment: Yea I know I know, but why is his problem `angular.js:14516 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] error` appearing? This is the question.

Comment: I'll be honest and say that I don't see what really causes his problem, but I think it's a waste of time figuring this out, If he will use the code I gave him it should work.

Comment: I see so many problems on Stackoverflow in that way the problem itself is sometimes more interesting than the solution. This question is one of this. Thats why I don't agree with refactoring answers here. The users approach should work.

Comment: He could also write his code like this: `[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])]`.
It doesn't mean he will get very far with that